# Let $B_{m \times n} = P_{m \times m} A_{m \times n}$ where $P$ is a product of elementary matrices. When is $P$ unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $ m \times n$ matrices , such that $B = PA$ where $P$ is a product of [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix). Now, when $rank(A) < m$  does it necessarily mean that $P$ is not unique and when $rank(A)=m$ does it imply that $P$ is unique?

**Verification for special cases:**

Suppose, $B=P_{1}A$ and $B=P_{2}A$

$ => 0= (P_{1}-P_{2})A$.

Thus, when $A=0$ i.e. $rank(A)=0<m$, $P$ is not unique. This special case supports my first statement.

Similarly, when $A$ is a square invertible matrix (and thus, so is $B$) then, 
$rank(A)=m$, and  $P=BA^{-1}$ . Thus, $P$ is unique. This scenario supports my second statement.

But, the proof (or counter example) eludes me in both the cases.

Comment: $B=P_{1}A$ and $B=P_{2}A$ imply $(P_{1}-P_{2})A=0$, not $B$.

Comment: Oh! sorry for the typo.

Comment: Isn't every matrix a product of elementary matrices?

Comment: Every invertible matrix is a product of elementary matrices.